# about 4k video error in Cobalt browser

Tags: cobalt

### Current status

-[current status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smqRI.jpg)

### Desired result

-I wish the video was played without stopping.

During the 4k video test in Cobalt version (10.52708), the video stops after a certain amount of time and only the loading progress is returned.

- Did I make the wrong porting?
- Then why are these problems occurring?

I would be grateful if you could answer the question.

Thank you.

Comment: Without any code or other information your guess is as good as ours.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how often do you see this issue? Can you also test with Cobalt RC_9 branch? *master* is under very active development

In the mean time, I will analyze our server log for your playback from our server. By the way, when did you take the screenshot picture? I need the exact time and your time zone.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
1. It is always generated in the vp9 codec.
2. Do I have to test on RC_9 (9.55360)? Can not test in version 9.28152?

Comment: The screenshot was taken about 10:19 am in Korea time.

Comment: 1. We serve 4k stream only with VP9 so that doesn't matter. My question is how often do you see the issue? Is it 100% reproducible?


2. 9.29152 should work IMO but I recommend you to work with the up-to-date one.

Comment: 1. 100% reproduced.
2. As you said, I tested with version 9.34413 which is one version higher than 9.28152, and the same thing happens.
3. I want to clone RC9 from http://https.cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt, how do I clone it?
I use the command "git clone https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt" to get the latest transition. I want to download RC9.

Comment: RC_9 is a git branch, you can fetch RC_9 branch in this way.

1. git clone https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt
2. git checkout RC_9

Comment: I have confirmed whether to play 4k video (vp9) in RC_9. Thank you, Daniel.
It worked on 1920 * 1080, but stopped on 3840 * 2160. Is this part of our platform problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me the values of SB_MEDIA_SOURCE_BUFFER_STREAM_AUDIO_MEMORY_LIMIT and SB_MEDIA_SOURCE_BUFFER_STREAM_VIDEO_MEMORY_LIMIT in configuration_public.h?  As Daniel suggested, upgrade to COBALT_9 may solve this issue.

Comment: SB_MEDIA_SOURCE_BUFFER_STREAM_AUDIO_MEMORY_LIMIT (3U * 1024U * 1024U)
SB_MEDIA_SOURCE_BUFFER_STREAM_VIDEO_MEMORY_LIMIT(16U * 1024U  * 1024U)

i will try COBALT_9

thank u for reply.

Comment: You can use the following memory settings for 4k playback:
1. memory buffer limit = 80 MB.
2. video buffer limit = 60 MB.
3. audio buffer limit = 5 MB.

Comment: thank you for reply, xiaoming
but, I set the size of the memory you suggested, but when playing 3840 * 2160 video on our platform, the 4k video stops.
1.  Is it a memory problem that runs on 1920 * 1080 but stops on 3840 * 2160?
Or am I not good at porting?