# Is it possible to play UHD (3840x2160) video on cobalt?

Tags: cobalt

The vp9 codec will play 1920 * 1080 video, but will stop midway when playing 3840 * 2160 video.

I want the UHD video(3840 * 2160) to play.

1. Is it a memory issue?
2. If it's not a memory issue, am I not ported well?

(cobalt version - RC_9)

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970663/about-4k-video-error-in-cobalt-browser

Comment: thank u . I resolved it

Answer (score 0):

For the history, this issue was fixed by setting *cobalt_media_buffer_initial_capacity* to 80 * 1024 * 1024.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38486998

Comment: Thanks for reply.
That's what I posted. Thank you anyway.